# How to stop Hibernate from spamming the logs

Tags: java, hibernate, google-app-engine, logging

I have hibernate running on app-engine and hibernate logs so much debug infos to the console/log (see attached screenshot) and I can't figure out how to stop it.

My log4j.properties looks like that:

```
# Root logger option
log4j.rootLogger=WARNING, stdout

# Direct log messages to stdout
log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.Target=System.out
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n

log4j.logger.org.hibernate=WARNING
```

So this normally should only log warnings right?

My logging.propertis looks like that (But I guess hibernate does not care about that because it uses log4j):

```
java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.level = SEVERE
```

[image]

Comment: Stop using Hibernate. :)

Comment: I know. That's why it is a comment and not an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Log4J the keyword is WARN not WARNING. Thats Java Util Logging. See [here](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/Level.html).